# Storing api keys on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables

I have this line of code that I am running under development.rb:

```
BlockIo.set_options :api_key=> BLOCK_IO_API_KEY, :pin => BLOCK_IO_PIN, :version => 2
```

I want to be able to run in my terminal:

```
rails c ENV['BLOCK_IO_API_KEY']="1234-3434-3434" ENV['BLOCK_IO_PIN']="ohlalala"
```

and then in production, use the heroku command: `heroku config:set GITHUB_USERNAME=joesmith`

I cannot figure out where to store the ENV variables and how to go about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference link: https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

In Development environment you can place environment variable in .env file in app directory.

For eg:

```
 AUTH0_CLIENT_ID= 'abc'
 AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET= 'bcd'
 AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:3000/auth/auth0/callback
```

In order to use this :

```
ENV['AUTH0_CLIENT_ID'],
ENV['AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET'],
ENV['AUTH0_DOMAIN'],
```

and then in production, use the heroku command:

```
heroku config:set GITHUB_USERNAME=joesmith
```

you will find this when you login with heroku,

```
  1) then select app
  2) go to settings
  3) click on Reveal config variable

 here you will get the env variable that you have set through console.
```

Comment: where do you place the .env file ?

Comment: @Antoine Inside rails app directory


path:    project_name/.env